# Delete a file without initially declare a variable of its path

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete a file without initially  declare a variable of its path.
I tried this code, but I got

> Automation error

```
    Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\Query1.XLS")
    wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Kill (wb1.FullName)   ‘`Automation error` on this line
```

If I initially  declared a variable of its path, the code works without problem

```
Dim wb1_Path As String: wb1_Path = wb1.FullName
Kill (wb1_Path)
```

Comment: You can't delete `ThisWorkbook` if it's open (and it must be...) - you will get "Permission denied"

Comment: @Tim Williams ,sure you are correct. I made a mistake when I adapted code on question, I posted the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access a property of the workbook after it is closed.  You can, however, change the workbooks `ChangeFileAccess` to `xlReadOnly` and delete the file while the workbook is open.

```
Sub CloseAndDestroy(wb As Workbook)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With wb
        .ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
        Kill .FullName
        .Close False
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```